# Bind and unbind events jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I am allowing user to change font size in my website, every time user clicks on id `"Large"` 1px gets added to the font, and likewise on clicking on `"small"` 1px gets decreased.

Also user is not allowed to click on the same button twice, so I am unbinding click event on that button, but is allowed to click after clicking on other buttons, here I am using bind click event, but it doesn't seem to work after unbind.

```js
$("#large").on("click", function() {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $("#medium").bind('click');
    $("#small").bind('click');
    $("div").children().each(function() {
        var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
        size = size + 1 + "px";
        $(this).css({
            'font-size': size
        });
    });

});

$("#medium").on("click", function() {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $("#large").bind('click');
    $("#small").bind('click');
    $("div").children().each(function() {
        var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
        size = size + 0 + "px";
        $(this).css({
            'font-size': size
        });
    });
});

$("#small").on("click", function() {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $("#medium").bind('click');
    $("#small").bind('click');
    $("div").children().each(function() {
        var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
        size = size - 3 + "px";
        $(this).css({
            'font-size': size
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <a href="" id="large">Large</a>
 <a href="" id="medium">Medium</a>
 <a href="" id="small">Small</a>

  <div>
        <p>Lorem ispsum dolor</p>
        <h1>Lorem ispsum dolor Lorem ispsum dolor Lorem ispsum dolor</h1>
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
  </div> 
 

        

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Nag/etsbapgu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach results in huge code duplication. The better option would be to store font diff in data-* attribute and bind a hanlder once. Then just check previous diff set by the handler.

This would allow you to simply add more links in future (say Extra Small, or Extra Large) w/o touching your code.

```js
$('[data-font]').click((function(current){

  return function(e) {
     var $this = $(this),
         font = parseInt($this.data('font')),
         // remove previous diff and add new
         diff = -current + font;
         
     e.preventDefault();
         
     // same button click
     if(current === font) return
         
     // save for the next call
     current = font;
     
     $('div').children().css('font-size', function() {
       return parseFloat($(this).css('font-size')) + diff + 'px';
     }) 
     
  }
 
}(0)))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <a href="" data-font="+3">Large</a>
 <a href="" data-font="0">Medium</a>
 <a href="" data-font="-3">Small</a>

  <div>
        <p>Lorem ispsum dolor</p>
        <h1>Lorem ispsum dolor Lorem ispsum dolor Lorem ispsum dolor</h1>
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
  </div>
```